# `<` character in exec task is breaking my Phing build script

Tags: mysql, phing

I'm trying to setup an mysql import script in Phing, but the "<" is causing XML errors.  Any ideas?

```
<exec command="mysql -u${mysql.username} -p${mysql.password} -h ${mysql.server} ${mysql.database} < ${sql.file}" />
```

I'm looking at making dbDeploy doing this, but it'd be great if there was an easy way for this to work (single line command versus the multi-line setup of dbDeploy)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Escape the character by replacing it with `&lt;`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Phing, but it may not be executing the command in a shell, so the redirect operator won't work (it may be treating the operator as an argument to `mysql` itself).

Instead of `< ${sql.file}`, try `-e 'source ${sql.file}'`, so your whole line is:

```
<exec command="mysql -u${mysql.username} -p${mysql.password} -h ${mysql.server} ${mysql.database} -e 'source ${sql.file}'" />
```

See the [MySQL batch mode documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-mode.html).

Comment: This is great. I was looking for this syntax and couldn't find it! Thanks a lot!